# Pagination in woocommerce - Limiting page-numbers

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, pagination

The below code is displaying pagination as follows - `1 2 3...6 7 8 9 >`

Whereas I just want to display - `1 2...8 9 >`

Basically I just don't want the pagination to be more than a line if I have more than 500 products.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$total   = isset( $total ) ? $total : wc_get_loop_prop( 'total_pages' );
$current = isset( $current ) ? $current : wc_get_loop_prop( 'current_page' );
$base    = isset( $base ) ? $base : esc_url_raw( str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', remove_query_arg( 'add-to-cart', get_pagenum_link( 999999999, false ) ) ) );
$format  = isset( $format ) ? $format : '';

if ( $total <= 1 ) {
    return;
}
?>
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
    <?php
    echo paginate_links(
        apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_pagination_args',
            array( // WPCS: XSS ok.
                'base'      => $base,
                'format'    => $format,
                'add_args'  => false,
                'current'   => max( 1, $current ),
                'total'     => $total,
                'prev_text' => is_rtl() ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;',
                'next_text' => is_rtl() ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;',
                'type'      => 'list',
                'end_size'  => 3,
                'mid_size'  => 3,
            )
        )
    );
    ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Changed mid_size and end_size value to 1.